# Open .pl file and close current one in SWI - Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have created two different .pl files in SWI-Prolog for a text adventure game. They are two different missions.

Is there any way at the end of the first mission to open the second mission (the second .pl file) and close the first one?

Also, what would be better: To create N .pl files for my N missions or one big .pl file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your initial impulse in thinking that using a number of module files would be best. I imagine that one reason for using different files would be to provide different name spaces for facts and rules which would be best expressed using the same predicates. So that, for instance, `Description` would be different for `room(1, Description)` in mission 1 than in mission 2.

One way of achieving this would be by accessing private, non-exported predicates in each of the different mission-modules. (*Aside*: I read Jan Wielemaker caution against this practice somewhere, but I'm not sure why, nor am I sure that I did read this.)

Here's a possible pattern I threw together:

Given a main file, 'game.pl', with the following program,

```
:- use_module([mission1, mission2]).

start :-
    playing(mission1).

playing(CurrentMission) :-
    read(Command),
    command(CurrentMission, Command),
    playing(CurrentMission).

command(_, quit) :- write('Good bye.'), halt.
command(CurrentMission, Command) :-
    ( current_predicate(CurrentMission:Command/_)  % Makes sure Command is defined in the module.
    ->  CurrentMission:Command                     % Call Command in the current mission-module
    ;   write('You can\'t do that.'),              % In case Command isn't defined in the mission.
    ).
```

and these mission modules,

In file 'mission1.pl':

```
:- module(mission1, []).

turn_left :-
    write('You see a left-over turnip').

eat_turnip :-
    write('You are transported to mission2'),
    playing(mission2).                         % Return to the prompt in `game` module, but with the next module.
```

In file 'mission2.pl':

```
:- module(mission2, []).

turn_left :-
    write('You see a left-leaning turncoat.').
```

Then we can play this shitty game:

```
?- start.
|: turn_left.
You see a left-over turnip
|: eat_turnip.
You are transported to mission2
|: turn_left.
You see a left-leaning turncoat.
|: quit
|: .
Good bye.
```

The specifics of this program are problematic for a number of reasons. For instance, I expect we might rather have a single predicate that handles navigating through places, and that we'd rather describe places and object that react to different commands in our missions, rather than account for every possible command. But the general principle of using the different files would still work.

Another approach would be to use `consult/1` and `unload_file/1` to load and unload modules, in which case you should be able to use their public, exported predicates instead of calling them by module. Documentation for those and related predicates can be found in the manual in the section ["Loading Prolog Source Files"](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=consulting).

Comment: what does `module` do?

Comment: The main reason I don't want to create one big file is because it would be 10000 lines of code,hence making it hard to read/edit/whatever

Comment: @NickShev Ah! `module/2` declares the current file to be a module! The second argument (empty lists in this case) is where you put exported predicates. If, for instance, you where you using the other approach I mention (`conulst/1` and `unload_file/1`) then you might want to export, e.g., the places in each mission: `:- module(mission1, [place/3])` (this supposes that each place is described by a 3-arity predicate, like, maybe, place(<name>,<description>,<present objects>) ). Documentation SWI modules is [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=modules).

Comment: so you suggest to create one big file?

Comment: @NickShev No--sorry: there is some miscommunication. I *would* use the module system so that *each mission would be kept in its own module file* (as outlined above). The reason to declare the files to be modules is this: you can refer predicates to particular modules (as demonstrated in my answer). If, for instance, you end up using dynamic predicates in your game, you can assert facts that are true in one mission but false in another by using, e.g., `mission1:assertz(completed)`.  Then `mission1:completed` is true, but `mission2:completed` could still be false.

Comment: I am using dynamic predicates on both missions. On the example you posted, I use `module/2` on both missions, then I run the first mission?

Comment: It might help to read the documentation on SWI modules, linked in an earlier comment. I have put [the files for this example on github](https://github.com/aBathologist/game_example) -- that might make things clearer. My example consists of three files: 'game.pl', 'missio1.pl', and 'mission2.pl'. The two mission files are declared to be modules using `module/2`. 'game.pl' loads these modules with `use_module/1`. To use: load 'game.pl', then start running the interactive loop with `start/1`. Keep in mind, this example is crappy and just for the sake of illustration. Let me know if still unclear.